# How to obtain the 301/302 website redirect location from the http response and follow it?

Tags: perl, redirect, mechanize, lwp-useragent

I have been trying to obtain the 301/302 redirect location from the http response using **perl Mechanize ([WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW::Mechanize)),** however have been having problems extracting it from the response using things like response->header and so on.

**Can anyone help with extracting the redirect location from the http responses from websites that use 301 or 302 redirects please?**

I know what I want to do and how to do it once I have this redirection location URL as I have done more complex things with Mechanize before, but I'm just having real problems with getting the location (or any other response fields) from the http response.

**Your help would be much appreciated, Many thanks**, CM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its a redirect, `WWW::Mechanize` would use `$mech->redirect_ok();` while `request()`ing to follow the redirect URL (this is an LWP method).

Note -

> WWW::Mechanize's constructor pushes `POST` on to the agent's
>   requests_redirectable list

So you wouldn't have to worry about pushing `POST` to the `requests_redirectable` list.

If you want to be absolutely certain that the program is redirecting your URLs and log every redirect in a log file (or something), you can use `LWP`'s `simple_request` and  `HTTP::Response`'s `is_redirect` to detect redirects, something like this-

```
use WWW::Mechanize; 

$mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();  
$mech->stack_depth(0);

my $resp = $mech->simple_request( HTTP::Request->new(GET => 'http://www.googl.com/') );
if( $resp->is_redirect ) {
  my $location = $resp->header( "Location" );
  my $uri = new URI( $location );
  print "Got redirected to URL - $uri\n";    
  $mech->get($uri);
  print $mech->content;
}
```

`is_redirect` will detect both 301 and 302 response codes.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried using the redirect_ok. It didn't appear to work. Am I correct in thinking that this redirect_ok should automatically take me to the redirected site? And from then I should be able to do a mech->content and view the page content from the redirected site?  A code example would be extremely useful if possible so I can check I was using it correctly, thanks a lot

Comment: Can you post the piece of code here so that we can help better?

Comment: Currently working on an iPad so not at present, but what I am looking to achieve is as follows

Comment: Currently working on an iPad so not at present, but what I am looking to achieve is as follows for a site that has a 301/302 redirect.        use Mechanize;  www::Mechanize->new;   If r->code = 301{  response->header->('Location');   Follow the redirect location URL;    print $mech->content;      . Something like this. If your could show me the code to do this that would be excellent because I just can't get it working. Thanks a lot

Comment: Updated the answer as per your requirement @user1617711

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, that's exactly what I was lookin for, I will give that a go tomorrow and let you know how I get on with it. As for the jjbsports URL I was supposed to say that an ip address I have been using for testing redirects to jjbsports, my mistake.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

[WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW::Mechanize) should automatically follow redirects (unless you've told it not to via  `requests_redirectable`), so you should not need to do anything.

EDIT: just to demonstrate:

```
DB<4> $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;

DB<5> $mech->get('http://www.preshweb.co.uk/linkedin');

DB<6> x $mech->uri;
0  URI::http=SCALAR(0x903f990)
  -> 'http://www.linkedin.com/in/bigpresh'
```

... as you can see, WWW::Mechanize followed the redirect, and ended up at the destination, automatically.

Updated with another example as requested:

```
DB<15> $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;

DB<16> $mech->get('http://jjbsports.com/');

DB<17> x $mech->uri;
0  URI::http=SCALAR(0x90988f0)
 -> 'http://www.jjbsports.com/'
DB<18> x substr $mech->content, 0, 40;
0  '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML'
DB<19> x $mech->title;
0  'JJB Sports | Trainers, Clothing, Football Kits, Football Boots, Running'
```

As you can see, it followed the redirect, and `$mech->content` is returning the content of the page.  Does that help at all?

Comment: I thought it did automatically follow redirects. But on a website that has 301 or 302 redirect it did not print anything out when I done a $print mech->content after.

Comment: An example site that has a 301/302 redirect is jjbsports.com, could you show me how you would follow the redirect and then print the content from the page you have been redirected too. Your help is much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Updated answer with second example using jjbsports.com as requested.  (Just in case you're not familiar with the perl debugger, "x" is a short command to dump out its argument.  From a normal script, you could say e.g. `print $mech->content` instead.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I Know of the perl debugger, never used it before though. Will look into it more though because it's clearly very useful. Will let you know if I manage to do it.

Comment: It's certainly a useful tool - `perldoc perldebtut` will give you some help getting started.  You could also look at Devel::REPL or `tinyrepl` provided by Eval::WithLexicals.

Comment: Also, if this answer helped you, please accept it  by clicking the tick icon :)